# Clear the navigation stack after Logout - Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I have a gmail add-on with CardAction - Logout:

[image]

And if in stack navigation there are few cards and user make "Logout" - appears "Back Arrow":

[image]

This is my logoutAction, it works fine, but do you have any ideas how to disable this back-arrow?

```
function logoutAction(e) {

  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();

  return CardService.newAuthorizationException()
  .setAuthorizationUrl(service.getAuthorizationUrl())
  .setResourceDisplayName("MY_PROJECT")
  .throwException();
}
```

This is my simple Card, where I use my logoutAction:

```
function afterImportScreenBuild() {

    var action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('logoutAction');

    var cardHeader = CardService.newCardHeader()
        .setTitle("MY_HEADER");

    var viewButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText("BTN")
        .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
            .setUrl("https://test.com/"));

    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(cardHeader);

    var section = CardService.newCardSection();

    var textKeyValue = CardService.newKeyValue()
        .setContent("MY_TIMELINE")
        .setButton(viewButton);

    card.addCardAction(CardService.newCardAction().setText('Logout').setOnClickAction(action));
    section.addWidget(textKeyValue);
    card.addSection(section);

    return card.build();
}
```

If my `logoutAction` would return `ActionResponseBuilder` I could use `popToRoot()`:

`CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(
    CardService.newNavigation().popToRoot()
).build()`

But in `logoutAction` I need to return `newAuthorizationException()` and I have no ideas how I can сlear my navigation stack.

Comment: @lambichus thank you for your response. I also provided the card where I called the `logoutAction`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but let me say a few things I see

```js
function logoutAction(e) {

  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();

}
```

With this function you completed the logout process, so, my question here is:

Do you really need to return anything there?

Because if not, we are done.

If we really need the return, we could always use a [`setCustomUiCallback(callback)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/authorization-exception#setcustomuicallbackcallback) on the `newAuthorizationException()` and make the `popToRoot()` call on there, showing the card you wish and avoiding the go back arrow.